# How to programatically 'login' a user based on 'remember me' cookie when using j2ee container authentication?

Tags: java, authentication, servlets, cookies

i'm using form based authntication in my WAR.
i want to implement a 'remember me' cookie
so:
1) how can i intercept the authentication before user is redirected to the form?
2) say i checked the cookie and its fine, how do i actually login the user?

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is to use a [`Filter`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/filters-137243.html) which will check that the cookie is there and log the user with your login system.