# How to securely implement "remember me in this computer" using stripes framework?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, stripes

I want to implement "remember me on this computer" using stripes framework. I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/396543/how-to-programatically-login-a-user-based-on-remember-me-cookie-when-using-j2); but stripes does not directly use servlets. So I am confused. Is there any way to securely implement "remember me" option using stripes ?

Answer (score 2):

Other question, that you mentioned, has a good suggestion. And it has nothing to do with specific framework like Stripes. For as long as you run web application, you can always set up Filter for your requests. In filter you can alter request to indicate that it is authenticated or reject it.

[This article](http://www.stripesframework.org/display/stripes/State+Management) talks about some relevant state management issues in Stripes. It, particularly, mentions access to cookies.

Answer (score 2):

I do not know what you mean by "securely". But if you want to set a cookie you can use the standard provided in javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse. You can retrieve it from the ActionBeanContext: http://stripes.sourceforge.net/docs/current/javadoc/net/sourceforge/stripes/action/ActionBeanContext.html#getResponse()